# SwiftUI Argument passed to call that takes no arguments

Tags: swift, swiftui

**Error :** Argument passed to call that takes no arguments

**Explanation :** I have 2 different views, `ContentView` and `MainView`. There is a `@Binding` variable in `MainView` which is `@Binding var showMenu: Bool`. When I try to call `MainView` with the an argument, I get the error specified above.

**Code Snippets :**

```
struct ContentView: View {
@State var showMenu = false
var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { geometry in
        MainView(showMenu: $showMenu)
            .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height)
            .offset(x: self.showMenu ? geometry.size.width/2 : 0)
            .disabled(self.showMenu ? true : false)
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
struct MainView: View {
@Binding var showMenu: Bool
//unrelated variable declarations
init() {
    //unrelated code
}
var body: some View {
    //unrelated code
}
```

Comment: Can you show how the "unrelated code" in the `init()` initialises `showMenu`? What you _should_ be doing is to have the initialiser accept a `Binding<Bool>` and assign it to `showMenu`, and that makes me wonder how you are currently initialising `showMenu`.

Comment: The code inside init() is
`UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(#colorLiteral(red: 0.7450980544, green: 0.1568627506, blue: 0.07450980693, alpha: 1))`
`UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]`
`UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
init() {
    //unrelated code
}
```

When you said that, you said that the only to make a MainView is by saying `MainView()`. So it is indeed true that you now can't say `MainView(showMenu:...)`.

You have three main choices that I can see:

- Delete the whole `init()`.
- Replace the whole `init()` with something like this:

  ```
  init(showMenu: Binding<Bool>) {
      self._showMenu = showMenu
      // other stuff?
  }
  ```
- Rethink the architecture. (We'd need to see more of what this binding is for.)

Comment: The code inside init() is 3 lines of UINavigationBar with barTintColor, titleTextAttributes and isTranclucent. Can I transfer these to somewhere else and if I can, how?

Comment: Would those be more appropriate in `onAppear`? But honestly I don't even know if that sort of appearance-proxy code is proper to SwiftUI. Does SwiftUI even _have_ UINavigationBars?

Comment: @matt `onAppear` is probably too late for that. SwiftUI navigation bars are very hacky, you usually just set `.appearance()` inside `init` (your second choice)